# Echo output of telnet command via bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, telnet

I would like to initiate a telnet session, send a command, and store the output in a variable using bash. To do this manually, I do:

```
telnet ip port
>command1
```

However, I'm not sure how to script this. I could easily echo something if I was just retrieving the output of something directly with `command1`, but I'm not sure how to bring the telnet connection into the equation.

I've tried the following command:

```
command1 | telnet ip port
```

This seems to start the telnet session, but then it tells me that the command was not found

Answer (score 1):

I think that should be:

```
cat file_with_command_in | telnet ip port
```

that way you send all input including newlines etc. (Which I suppose you could do from the command line, but a file is easier).

Comment: Regarding `file_with_command_in`, do you mean I need to create a file with that one command, then invoke it from my main script file? If so, is there a way to do it all in one script? My overall goal is to run one script that is bound to a hotkey, save part of the output with `command1`, then store it as a variable for the rest of my script. Perhaps I should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: What you were doing was sending the output of command1 to telenet. In order to send 'command1' literally you would need `echo command1 | telnet .....` Using cat filename is usually easier, but if the requirment is very simple then echo is the same.

Comment: The response I get is "Trying *IP*. Connected to *IP*. Escape character is '^]'. Connection closed by foreign host."